# Cannot open "DetailPage" because of crash Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic5

i migrated everything from ionic 4 to 5 and everything works but the detailsPage, how to do a proper navigation? I configured my ion-card like this:

```
<ion-card [routerLink]="['/objects/', object.id]" routerDirection="forward">
....
</ion-card>
```

// ERROR

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
```

// DETAILSPAGE HTML

```
<ion-img *ngIf="object.image" src="{{ object.image }}"></ion-img>
<ion-img *ngIf="!object.image" src="https://defaultimage.com"></ion-img>
```

// DETAILSPAGE TS

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log("Into ngoninit")
this.objectId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
this.objectRef = this.af.doc(`objects/${this.objectId}`);
console.log(this.objectRef , this.objectId)

if (this.objectId) {
  this.loadobject(this.objectId)
}
this.gotClicked()
}

async loadObject(objectId) {
    console.log("into loadobject", objectId)
    this.af.collection<object>('objects')
      .doc<object>(objectId)
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.object = data
        console.log(data)
        this.fullObject = data.title + ' by '
          + data.name + '\n\n'
          + data.body + '\n\n'
          + data.location
      });
  }
```

Cannot understand what im doing wrong because didnt change the way to do lazy loading routes but it crashes, i'm trying to downgrade angular versions and everything but it still remains, where should I start to find the fail? **I'm using tabs and lazy loading**. I had to migrate it because giving me strange behaviour on build --prod, but here the problem is It crashes at click on a loop of ion-cards and it looks it's something about "routes" or "detailspage"

UPDATED:

MAINPAGE.HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects | async">
    <ion-card [routerLink]="['/object/', object.id]" routerDirection="forward">
        <ion-img class="blur-filter" src="{{ object.image }}"></ion-img>
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>
                <ion-grid>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col>
                            <div class="ion-text-start">
                                {{ object.title }}
                            </div>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>
            </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-start">
                    <ion-col size='3'>
                        <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-badge color="secondary">{{ object.clicks }}</ion-badge>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col size='3'>
                    </ion-col>
                    <!--ion-col>

                    </ion-col-->
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                      
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: `Cannot read property 'images' of undefined` , you should post full of your code inlcude html and component.ts for us so we can help you.

Comment: in your updated , i cant see varible `images` you use. Get notice with varible `images` you use in HTML.

Comment: images came from object.images (here i put object.image)

Comment: the error came from `object.images` if you use it somewhere just post it , here you use `object.image`. It's not realate to your error. I think so. Post your full HTML code , i can see and help you find what the error came

Comment: updated, forget about "images" it's "image"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Cannot read property 'image' of undefined` means that you're trying to access the `image` property but that object is undefined/null. This could be happening because the view is trying to show the image but the object has not been initialized yet in the component's code.

The first thing you'd need to do to avoid that error is to replace every instance of `object.image` in the view by `object?.image` so that Angular doesn't try to access the `image` property if the `object` is still null/undefined.

Another suggestion – it's better to use `[src]="..."` instead of `src={{ ... }}`. So in that case your code would look like this:

````
<ion-img *ngIf="object?.image" [src]="object.image"></ion-img>
<ion-img *ngIf="!object?.image" src="https://defaultimage.com"></ion-img>```
````

Comment: updated, do you have some idea how to fix it? and yesss thank you so much, i was on need to know such things, but the real problem is the detailspage isnt appearing or its kinda broken, and don't know how to fix it... 1 month im spending on it. I migrated it from ionic 4 to 5 with everything updated and still having problems... and the old version is doing it, also the problem when i was running it okay, when i was building the --prod or release, was with blank pages (running without prod was working perfectly)

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the process of migrating a big app as well so I guess I'd recommend you to replace the details page by a completely blank page, created by running the `ionic generate ...` command. Once the navigation to that empty page works, you can start by mocking the data in the component (using hardcoded objects or arrays) and adding the code in the view, piece by piece. That way you'll find what part of the code is causing the issues and it will be easier to understand what is going on and why.

Comment: Yes i did it with copy+past the src folder, ok i will follow your advice, thank you really so much, i'm new on it so, i'm really pissed of with compatibilities/versions etc... Can you give me some advices about if i have to use node 10 instead of 12 and something like that? it feels that nothing works at all...

Comment: Yeah, it can be frustrating at first, but it doesn't happen often (most of the releases don't have any breaking changes). About node, [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/environment#node-npm) recommend the latest LTS version.